# Loop to apply the code on different data and save the plots in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, pdf, plot

I have the dataframe `df` which looks like following:

```
df <- structure(list(times = c(724L, 1624L, 1569L, 2532L, 1271L, 2442L, 
757L, 848L, 3675L, 1229L, 1582L, 1257L, 1270L, 555L, 357L, 1133L, 
633L), Samples = structure(c(1L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("Sample1", 
"Sample10", "Sample11", "Sample12", "Sample13", "Sample14", "Sample15", 
"Sample16", "Sample17", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", 
"Sample6", "Sample7", "Sample8", "Sample9"), class = "factor"), 
    vital_status = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), years = c(1.983561644, 
    4.449315068, 4.298630137, 6.936986301, 3.482191781, 6.690410959, 
    2.073972603, 2.323287671, 10.06849315, 3.367123288, 4.334246575, 
    3.443835616, 3.479452055, 1.520547945, 0.978082192, 3.104109589, 
    1.734246575), Gene1 = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 1.2, 3.8, 2.3, 3.8, 
    0.4, 0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.8, 1.8, 2.4, 3, 0.6), Gene2 = c(1.2, 
    3.8, 2.3, 3.8, 0.4, 0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 
    1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.6), Gene3 = c(2.3, 3.8, 0.4, 0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 
    0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6), Gene4 = c(3.8, 
    0.4, 0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.8, 1.8, 2.4, 3, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 
    0.6, 1.2, 3.8, 2.3), Gene5 = c(0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6, 
    0.5, 1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 7.7, 2.1, 0.9, 0.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

Using the above data I'm applying the following code in `R` initially on `Gene1`

```
library(survminer)
surv_rnaseq.cut <- surv_cutpoint(
  df,
  time = "years",
  event = "vital_status",
  variables = c("Gene1")
)

pdf("Gene1_Cuttpt.pdf")
plot(surv_rnaseq.cut, "Gene1", palette = "npg")
dev.off()

surv_rnaseq.cat <- surv_categorize(surv_rnaseq.cut)

library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(years, vital_status) ~ Gene1,
               data = surv_rnaseq.cat)
pdf("Gene1_Survival_high_vs_low_WithPvalue.pdf")
ggsurvplot(fit,
           pval = TRUE, conf.int = FALSE,
           risk.table = TRUE, # Add risk table
           risk.table.col = "strata", # Change risk table color by groups
           linetype = "strata", # Change line type by groups
           surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
           ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
           palette = c("#FF0027", "#060606"),
           xlim = c(0,10),
           break.x.by = 3,
           xlab="Time in years",
           risk.table.y.text.col = T, # colour risk table text annotations.
           risk.table.y.text = FALSE)
dev.off()
```

I want to apply the same code on other Genes (Gene2, Gene3, Gene4, Gene5) and save the plots all at a time by using a `R` loop

Can anyone tell me how to do that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't run it since I have no data. If there is a bug please provide some data. The code would be something like this

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
# vector with the variables to run through
genes <- c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5") 

for(i in 1:length(genes)){
surv_rnaseq.cut <- surv_cutpoint(
  df,
  time = "years",
  event = "vital_status",
  variables = c(genes[i]))

pdf(paste0(genes[i], "_Cuttpt.pdf"))
print(
plot(surv_rnaseq.cut, genes[i], palette = "npg")
)
dev.off()

surv_rnaseq.cat <- surv_categorize(surv_rnaseq.cut)


fit <- survfit(as.formula(paste0("Surv(years, vital_status) ~", genes[i])),
               data = surv_rnaseq.cat)

pdf(paste0(genes[i], "_Survival_high_vs_low_WithPvalue.pdf"))

print(
ggsurvplot(fit,
        pval = TRUE, conf.int = FALSE,
       risk.table = TRUE, # Add risk table
       risk.table.col = "strata", # Change risk table color by groups
       linetype = "strata", # Change line type by groups
       surv.median.line = "hv", # Specify median survival
       ggtheme = theme_bw(), # Change ggplot2 theme
       palette = c("#FF0027", "#060606"),
       xlim = c(0,10),
       break.x.by = 3,
       xlab="Time in years",
       risk.table.y.text.col = T, # colour risk table text annotations.
       risk.table.y.text = FALSE)
)
dev.off()
}
```

So basically you can use the paste() function and select the Gene 1-5 with i from vector genes. This replaces the situations where was "Gene1" in the code. In the case of the formula in survfit you can not simply use characters but fortunately you can do so by wrapping them into as.formula(). Everything else stays pretty much the same and pdf() and so on will create the plots of Gene selected with genes[i].